# How do you define @font-face in a CSSObject?

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, styled-components, emotion

Suppose I have the following `@font-face` rule(s) and I want to put them as a `CSSObject` instead of a flat string.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Blah';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src:
    url('./Blah-Normal.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./Blah-Normal.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Blah';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: bold;
  src:
    url('./Blah-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./Blah-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}
...
```

How can I define it as a `CSSObject`? I'm trying to pass it over to Mui's `MuiCssBaseline` and it takes a `CSSObject` or `string`. I'd like to pass a `CSSObject` so that I could add more CSS styling on it more easily and easier to read. But right now it is just a flat string containing only the `@font-face` definitions.

```
// import { CSSObject } from '@mui/material';
// import { CSSObject } from '@emotion/styled';
import { CSSObject } from 'styled-components';

const BlahCSSObject = {
  '@font-face': {
    // magic?
    src: [
      // it definitely don't like the following format
      url('./Blah-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('./Blah-Bold.woff') format('woff')
    ]
  },
  '@font-face': { // would cause dupe keys no?
    ...
  },
  ...
} as CSSObject;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use css method from styled-components.

```js
import { css } from 'styled-components'

const myOwnStyle = css`
  @font-face {
    // styles
  }
`
```

Comment: Tried, didn't work. `css` returns a `SerializedStyles` which is incompatible to `string | CSSObject` that the `MuiCssBaseline` is expecting.

Comment: Maybe using of plain css file for just adding font faces is a good solution and import it to your app and then with custom muiTheme which you are set you can access your font for using it every where